# See what indenting style is being used in Vim

Tags: indentation

I've recently started up a project using Typescript. When I start up Vim, open up a `.tsx` file and open a new line, it fails to indent:

[image]

I then open up a regular javascript file (`.js`), and return to my Typescript file. I then open a new line and it indents correctly:

[image]

I've tried turning on / off `autoindent` and `cindent`, and I've removed my plugins (installed via Pathogen) and brought them back and the problem seems to be consistent.

I presume there is some auto indenting being triggered by the opening of the `.js` file that persists to the typescript file, but I have no idea how to check / debug what is going on. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, this worked:

`autocmd BufEnter *.tsx :setlocal filetype=typescript`

That seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: The standard extension for TypeScript is `.ts` AFAIK. Either way, Vim doesn't have any `typescript` filetype as far as I can see, so it looks like you added a plugin to support this at some point?

Comment: See `:help new-filetype` (sections A and C) for the recommended methods of setting the filetype.